# PHP Loop based on PHP values

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am in the process of learning PHP and I am trying to start a loop based on the values taken from a MySQL table.

In the MySQL table I have a course name with a start_year and duration. What I would like to achieve is something along the following code example:

```
$results = $conn->query($sql);
for (int $i = $results as $row['start_year']; $i <= $results as $row['duration']; i++) {
    echo "<tr>" . $i . "</tr>";
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Code Update:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="wide" >Year</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<!-- Table body -->          
<tbody>
    <?php
    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$mysqldatabase;
        // try connecting to the database
        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword);
        // turn on PDO exception handling 
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // enter catch block in event of error in preceding try block
        echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
    try {
        $sql="SELECT *
        FROM courses
        WHERE courses.cid = \"". $_GET['courses'] . "\"
        ORDER BY courses.title";
    $results=$conn->query($sql);
    if ($results->rowcount()==0){
    } else {
        //generate table of results 
        foreach ($results as $row){
               $years=range($row['startYear'],$row['startYear']+$row['duration']-1);
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo implode(",",$years."</td></tr>");
        }
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

?>

Comment: Mostly depends on what `$conn->query($sql);` returns. It is an associative array? or is a `mysqli_result`? or a `PDOStatement`?

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned its a PDOStatement.

Comment: What is the expected output you're looking for... are you trying to just show the courses where a start year was less than x years (the duration) ago - therefore should still be current?

Comment: The result I was looking for was a list of years that the returned course would have. for example, Course Computer Science starts in year 1 and has a 4 year duration, so I would like a table that would contain the values between these numbers. Apologies for the delayed edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this answer on [the php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdo.query.php)

```
$results = $conn->query($sql);
foreach  ($results as $row){
    $years=range($row['start_year'],$row['start_year']+$row['duration']-1);
    echo implode(",",$years)."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I realized afterwards that the example I was using was the most simplified. This would only work if there were 2 values to be displayed. If a year had a start year of 1 and a duration of 4, I would like a table showing values 1,2,3,4.

Comment: ok, I've edited my answer, for the usage of range and implode read the manual.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I have added this as above but I am still getting no outputs.I have added a copy of the code below:
'code'

Comment: Hi, this helped me get to the solution! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your welcome. Just a small comment about your code update, can you reupdate this typo: `echo implode(",",$years."</td></tr>");` to `echo implode(",",$years)."</td></tr>";` (The closing parenthesis should be after $years)